# Implementing Different Build Configurations in Compose Multiplatform for Android and iOS

Tags: gradle, kotlin-multiplatform, buildconfiguration, compose-multiplatform

I am working on a project using Jetpack Compose Multiplatform, targeting both Android and iOS platforms. My aim is to implement different build configurations for UAT (User Acceptance Testing) and Production environments. Specifically, I need to configure the App Icon, App Name, and Base URL differently for each environment.

In the past, for Android-only projects, I have successfully used build flavors to manage different configurations. However, I am unsure how to approach this in a Compose Multiplatform context, where the codebase also includes iOS.

I would appreciate guidance on the following points:

1. App Icon and App Name: How can I set up different icons and app
   names for UAT and Production builds in a Compose Multiplatform
   project?
2. Base URL Configuration: What is the recommended way to configure
   different Base URLs for UAT and Production environments in a shared
   Kotlin Multiplatform codebase?
3. iOS-Specific Considerations: Are there any iOS-specific
   considerations I need to be aware of when configuring build variants
   in a Compose Multiplatform project?
4. Best Practices: Are there any best practices or common patterns for
   managing different build configurations in Compose Multiplatform
   projects?

Any code examples, documentation references, or insights from personal experiences would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you in advance for your assistance!

Answer (score -2):

You can check the below article link reference:

https://medium.com/@callmeryan/build-apps-for-ios-android-and-desktop-with-compose-multiplatform-jetbrains-kmp-webinar-3-of-4-3489003ed05d

Comment: I can't find anything specific to my question in that link. Sorry.